# Get jaydata to return objects synchronously

Tags: javascript, synchronization, jaydata

I have methods to Set and Get data from WEBSql scattered across my javascript. Here's my "get" function to fetch data using jayData :

```
function getProductRow(key){

    console.debug("Product key.. " + key);

    $data("Product")
        .query("it.Key == productKey", { productKey: key})
        .then(function(items) {
            items.forEach(function(item) {
               console.debug("item.value.. " + item.Value);
               return item.Value;
            });
         });    
}
```

And here's my js method which is called from various places, and which inturn, calls the `getProductRow` method:

```
function getProdValue(key) {
    console.debug("called getProdValue with " + key);

    var value = getProdRow(key);
    var prod = $.parseJSON(value);          
    // do stuff with prod       

}
```

The logs i see on my console are :

```
called getProdValue with abc111
Product key.. abc111
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
item.value.. // some stringified valid json string
```

Obviously, due to the asynchronous nature of jaydata, the control is returned to the calling function before the `item.Value` is retrieved, and parsing "undefined" gives me the syntax error. How can i make the whole call synchronous, so that control goes back to calling function only when `item.Value` is returned?

Answer (score 1):

You can not make it sync. From your code I guess that you read by primary key, so you'll need something like:

```
function getProdValue(key) {
       $data("Product").read(key)
       .then(function(product) {
            return $.parseJSON(product.value);
        });
 }
```

Comment: No, i do not read by its sequence number (if that is what you mean by primary key). the name of the column which stores the product key, happens to be "Key". I am hoping that will not be a problem, because i am able to retrieve the corresponding data (although asynchronously)

Comment: With your suggestion, the parsing will be successful. But The `getProdValue` method is called at various places, where an object is expected to be returned. Now _they_ will face the same problem that `getProductValue` method faced, when they try to do stuff with the return data. Isn't that correct? Is it possible to achieve what I am trying (synchronous calls) by using a licensed version?

Comment: sync is not possible as the underlying technology is async itself expect for some non-widely implemented methods that can be accessed only in webworkers